# Lync 2013 | Open Lync window shortcut key how to change

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-2013

I was using Lync 2010 for a long time... but now I have switched to Lync 2013 recently. The key to open Lync 2013 is changed to `Win+Y` from `Win+Q`...Is there any way to change this to old key as it was in 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AutoHotkey and run the following script:

```
#q::#y
```

I use Q out of old habit too.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but if any application relies on Win+Y, you will need to (at least temporarily) disable the script.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't be able to do anything about Win+Y as that is Lync's own hotkey. However, if another application uses Win+Q you would need to chose which would win. Since Lync 2010 uses Win+Q and Lync 2013 uses Win+Y it seems unlikely that an enterprise application would chose any of those for it's hotkeys.

Comment: It seems that I had a typo in my first comment. It should be Win+Q. I'm sure that there is a way to have auto hot key detect if Lync 2013 is open and run the command if it is.

Comment: My solution uses both hotkeys, and does not provide a way to remap Lync's hotkey and free up Win+Y. I am not familiar with a way to accomplish that.

Comment: Perfect, I've already got AHK running anyways :)